# Express v4.0.0 does not include --sessions command or cmd but prior versions do

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Since I'm not intimately familiar with Express, can anybody tell me why v4.0.0 doesn't include  --sessions as a command?

When I use version 3.4.8 this command is supported, but when I grab the newest version, I run into 2 issues:

1. The Express.cmd isn't generated (I'm running on Win8.1 x64) - Therefore I had to run `npm install express-generator`
2. No included support for the --sessions command

I might also be missing something and this was an intentional separation done by the Express team?

Comment: As part of the release of 4.x, nearly all of the formerly bundled middleware [has been moved to their own packages](https://github.com/senchalabs/Connect#middleware). `session()` is now [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-session). Only `express.static()` remains bundled. Docs: [Express: Migrating from 3.x to 4.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect middleware is no longer bundled with express. You have to install the session middleware yourself in express 4.x.  For a decent guide on updating see [this post](http://scotch.io/bar-talk/expressjs-4-0-new-features-and-upgrading-from-3-0).

```
%npm install express-session
```

then

```
var session = require ('express-session');
```

and replace

```
app.use(express.session());
```

with

```
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 100000 }}));
```